# Set default url parameter value when none is specified

Tags: javascript, html, url, url-parameters

I found this answer for getting URL arguments from JavaScript on the internet:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to modify this, so when no URL arguments are specified, a preset value will become the argument value.

eg. `index.html?value=1` would return 1,

If I set the default value to 2, and someone types `index.html` the variable value will be 2.

Comment: `getURLParameter(name, _default)` and if the result is `""` return `_default` ?

Comment: Ah, that works. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the best one. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an argument to specify the default value you would like if the key is missing:

```
function getURLParameter(name, _default) {
    var value = decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null
    return value !=null ? value : _default;
}
```

(FYI this implementation treats `;` as a delimiter: `k=a;b` would return `a`, this is a bit odd.)